# Attempting to checkout old file in an older branch with file in current new branch fails

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have an old branch which no longer exists locally called MDM-991/feature-pilot. This branch is was created in 2021. I have a new branch called MDM-1112 created from the master. I want to recover a file which has undergone lots of changes from the old MDM-991/feature-pilot branch . I did a checkout of the old branch and tried the following to get the old file but it did not work:

```
    > git checkout MDM-1112
    > cd mdm-flow-control-plane
    > git checkout MDM-991/feature-pilot  src/main/java/com/mdm/flows/planar/FlowControlPlane.java
```

That is the correct path for the file when I run an ls -al command.  I can navigate to it by typing  at the command prompt

> cd src/main/java/com/mdm/flows/planar
> and see the file. However,

> git checkout MDM-991/feature-pilot  src/main/java/com/mdm/flows/planar/FlowControlPlane.java

fails with the error:

error: pathspec 'src/main/java/com/mdm/flows/planar/FlowControlPlane.java' did not match any file(s) known to git

How is that possible? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the branch "no longer exists locally", you won't be able to get anything from it. Although the error message shown doesn't match that scenario, so maybe that's just a mistake in your explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you referring to a branch that doesn't exist?

If this branch is still in the remote repository, you need to reference it

```
git fetch origin
git checkout remote/origin/MDM-991/feature-pilot -- src/main/java/com/mdm/flows/planar/FlowControlPlane.java
```